# Kafka Producer Behaviour

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I set up Kafka on my localhost and tried monitoring the behaviour of Kafka Producer in case of network issues.

Even when all brokers are down, the producer is not giving any error.
I'm using a sync producer and Kafka version 0.8.

Is there any way in which the producer can receive an Exception if all the brokers are down?

Comment: How you are running your producer? Is it Console producer??

Comment: No. I made a producer in Java using the Producer API

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your producer configuration ([producer config](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newproducerconfigs))

Especially pay attention on the parameters:

```
  (METADATA_FETCH_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, 60000),
  (TIMEOUT_CONFIG, 10000),
  (RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 100),
  (RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 1000)
```

You sure have to change the parameters regarding your setup. All this params affect producer behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Please add exception handling in your producer :

```
try{
      Producer logic
}
catch (Exception ex) {
      String errorMsg = "Failed to publish events";
      logger.error("Failed to publish events", ex);
      result = Status.BACKOFF;
```

Please let me know if it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The newer 8.2 producer in [Java](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/Producer.java)/Scala (Async producer) has a Callback method passed for every message.  You can try and handle the failure in the callback .. retry probably. The callback method takes two parameters(Exceptionand MessageMetatData). Only one will be set at any time. Meatadata is set when your message was successfully sent, Exception in case something goes wrong.

With the sync producer though you will have to set max.retries and other configs as @leshkin pointed out.